# error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h

Tags: c, linux, gcc, bash

I used to be able to compile C programs, but now I can't:

```
$ cat helloworld.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

$ gcc helloworld.c
helloworld.c:1:19: error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h
```

Yes, I do have `/usr/include/stdio.h` .  Yes, `build-essentials` is installed.

This problem began after I modified my `~/.bashrc` to run a program installed in my user directory.  I know this is what's wrong because if I remove `~/.bashrc`, it works.

What environment variable would be shadowing `/usr/include` as an include path?

Comment: Pasting the contents of your `.bashrc` would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I had another GCC in my PATH:

```
$ which gcc
/home/joey/gcc4ti/bin/gcc
```

When I was trying to compile "Hello World", it was running a compiler for a 68000, not my system compiler :D

I had this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/home/joey/gcc4ti/bin:$PATH"
```

Because paths are scanned in order, the `gcc` in `/home/joey/gcc4ti/bin` is seen first.  I changed it to:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/joey/gcc4ti/bin"
```